# MarkLogic 9.0 32 bit ODBC driver failed SSAS Cube

Tags: sql-server, odbc, marklogic, ssas-tabular, marklogic-9

Hello i wan't to create an tabular cube with Microsoft SSAS on top of the MarkLogic 9.0 TDE views. Everything is ok including creating 32 bit ODBC driver on the MSSQL 2017 Server.

When i choise "import data" the list of tables / views are empty, if i choice "write query" i get the data from the view:

[image]

but whin i click on "ok" then i get the following error:

[image]

Has anyone a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Last I was aware, the 32-bit Windows Driver was not working right with MarkLogic 9. It's possible it's been updated, but we were unable to use it to connect Tableau with MarkLogic 9 a few weeks ago. I never heard back from support as to whether or not that issue was resolved. You might want to check with them.